# formatting R text output for beamer presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, beamer

I would like to format the R output when exporting my `rmd` file to a beamer presentation.

The following code shows standard behaviour and the use of LaTeX to place the output in a framed colorbox.

I am wondering whether there is an easier way to tell `knitr` to format the output in a like fashion.

````
---
author: name
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyvrb}
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

## standard output

```{r message=F, echo=F, comment=NA}
library(lmtest) # needed for coeftest()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(n)
model <- lm(y ~ x)
coeftest(model)
```

## formatted output {.fragile}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,rulecolor=\color{red},fontsize=\small,framerule=0.5mm,firstline=2]
```{r message=F, echo=F, comment=NA, results='asis'}
library(lmtest) # needed for coeftest()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
n <- 100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
x <- rnorm(n)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
y <- 2*x + rnorm(n)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
model <- lm(y ~ x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
coeftest(model)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
```
\end{Verbatim}
````

Reading [Karl Broman's webpage](https://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/figs_tables.html) I did note that the `kable` package can be used for formatting output produced by the `summary()` command. Unfortunately, I need `coeftest()` for specifying my standard errors, and I get an error message when using `kable(coeftest(model)$coef, digits=2)`.

Also, I do have a feeling that `knitr`'s  `render()` function could be used to reduce the output size and place it in some kind of box. If that is so, I would very much appreciate a pointer to a simple example.